# While reading excel row value it ignores decimal values like 45.4 it read as only 45

Tags: c#, oledb, import-from-excel

while reading excel row value it ignores decimal values like 45.4 it read as only 45. 
this is my code

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + strFileName + "; Extended Properties = \"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=2\";"); /*for office 2007 connection*/
conn.Open();

string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + Table + "]";
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);
System.Data.DataTable ExcelToDataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
adapter.Fill(ExcelToDataTable);
```

I want to read as 45.4 not only 45. please help?

Comment: What is your excel column type?

Comment: There's your problem right there